# Require.js Not Updating in Browser

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am having some issues developing an application with require.js. Whenever I edit a javascript file and save it in my code editor, the browser doesn't seem to register the change. I can refresh the page, but it still runs the old code. The problem is fixed by closing the tab and going re-opening the page, but there must be an easier way to do this. Has anyone else ever had this problem, and how did you fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the future, it helps if you include your code in a JSFiddle.

Comment: @SomeKittens I would under other circumstances, but I had this problem before and it seems to be code-independent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to the file that you specify as `data-main` (in most cases, `main.js`). Add this at the very first line:

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: "ts="+new Date().getTime()
});
```

Note that this should be removed for production.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working so far. [Here is a link](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs) to the documentation for this parameter is anyone else has the same problem.